# Suitescript - Using a dynamically created "fieldId" in the script

Tags: javascript, string, formula, netsuite, suitescript

I want to dynamically create a field id based upon results.   I have a very basic script showing what I am trying to do.  It continues to not retrieve information.   I have tried using + instead of concat (''custitem' + testtext + ''').  When I log the field name - it shows correctly 'custitemdoe_jane'.

You can see the script shows using the formula in two different ways.   Can this be done??

```
 /**
 * This script looks for RTAs - updates the purchase Order and the CT record
 * 
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
 
define(['N/file', 'N/search', 'N/record', 'N/format', 'N/email'],
        
function(file, search, record, format, email) {
    
    function execute(scriptContext) {
    var texty = '\'custitem';
    var testtext = 'doe_jane';
    var texty3 = '\'';
    var fieldname = texty.concat(testtext);
    var fieldname = fieldname.concat(texty3);
    
    log.debug('fieldname', fieldname);
```

// end result here is 'custitemdoe_jane' with the quotes

```
    var itemfix = record.load({
        type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM, 
        id: 488, 
        isDynamic: false
        });
            
        var values = itemfix.getText({fieldId: fieldname});   
        var values2 = itemfix.getValue({fieldId: fieldname});    
        log.debug('values', values);
        log.debug('values', values2);

       var values3 = itemfix.getText({fieldId: fieldname.concat(texty3)});   
        var values4 = itemfix.getValue({fieldId: fieldname.concat(texty3)});    
        log.debug('values', values3);
        log.debug('values', values4);
```

// all of these above are blank

```
        itemfix.save({
            enableSourcing: true
        });             
        }
        
return {execute: execute};
    
});
```

Comment: what's the point of all this code, if you always have virtually hardcoded values? you code will always have (if it works correctly) `fieldname = 'custitem_doe_jane'` or `fieldname = 'custitem_whatever_was_present_in_testtext_variable` ? So what's the point? If you always will change the value in `var testtext = ` why not to use it directly in the field name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can use template Literals which is a modern approach by switching Apiversion to 2.1 and do it like this.

const prefix = 'custitem_'

```
let fieldId = `${prefix}${itemfix.getText({fieldId: fieldname});}`
```

In any case i would check if this for instance *itemfix.getText({fieldId: fieldname})* returns a value before i create a fieldId based on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem, is that a field may not have quotes in its name. So you need to have `custitemdoe_jane` instead of `'custitemdoe_jane'`.

Provided you know, what you are doing (I have failed to get the purpose of your code), to generate `fieldname` based on a value changed in the `var testtext` you need at least:

instead of:

```
var texty = '\'custitem';
var testtext = 'doe_jane';
var texty3 = '\'';
var fieldname = texty.concat(testtext);
var fieldname = fieldname.concat(texty3);
```

have this (these are minimal modifications, for clarity):

```
var texty = 'custitem';
var testtext = 'doe_jane';
var fieldname = texty + testtext;
```

this way you'll have 'custitemdoe_jane' as a field name, **which is at least a valid name.**